# Overheating new MacBook Pro 13, 2017 year 7th generation

Tags: macos, macbook, macbook-pro

Overheating new MacBook Pro 13 2017 years 7th generation. Did anyone come across this? It seems to me that this is the process of Skype failing, since after its closure the problem disappears. Also it helps to restart. The temperature comes up to 60-70 degrees when running Skype. The laptop is on the table. Macbook just 3 days. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

You could see how much it’s working your cpu, or if it has any background apps doing anything. It could possibly be overworking it.

Comment: [Intel Power Gadget and System Monitor](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s588/sh/1d34ad5d-1bc4-48a9-8a45-6156f91bda1b/0b898c12c16a1bcd1c68aee8512d18ab) Thanks you for answer @TallonWatkins

Comment: @kryptoncode looks like chrome is running pretty high, but that’s normal. Try checking if you have the most recent version of OS and most recent Skype

Comment: I have the latest OS version and Skype. In Chrome open a 16 tabs. Now the temperature is normal, but I already afraid open Skype.